# Get email from Active Directory result

Tags: c#, active-directory

I have the following function, but I'm unable to get email and others stuff like phone number. What can I do to get that?

```
public static List<AdEmployees> CreateEmployeeList(string department)
    {
        List<AdEmployees> employees = new List<AdEmployees>();

        PrincipalContext pricipalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
        GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pricipalContext, department);

        if (group != null)
        {
            foreach (Principal principal in group.Members)
            {
                employees.Add(new AdEmployees() { name = principal.Name });
            }
        }
        return employees;
    }
```

string department is a given group in ad ( could be "guest" or "admin" or something else )

Comment: This may be useful: https://anyrest.wordpress.com/2010/10/14/how-to-use-ad-attributes-not-represented-in-userprincipal-groupprincipal-and-computerprincipal/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
PrincipalContext pricipalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
        GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pricipalContext, department);

        if (group != null)
        {
            foreach (Principal principal in group.Members)
            {
                UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pricipalContext, principal.Name);
                employees.Add(new AdEmployees() { name = user.Name });
            }
        }
```

Some Ad object like "Office" is not found this way. then you can try

```
UserPrincipal tu = principal as UserPrincipal;
DirectoryEntry de = tu.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;
var store = de.InvokeGet("physicalDeliveryOfficeName").ToString()
```